# Excel 2007 - Copy data to another sheet if it doesn't exist there

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm working on a file with three sheets.

The first sheet looks like this:

```
| ID | Data | Data | Data | Data | Sheet |
```

ID is a number. Data can be letters, numbers or combinations. Sheet is a dropdown list containing the names of the other two sheets. I want to copy the ID and 4 data columns to the sheet selected in the drop down, but ONLY if a row with the ID does not already exist on either sheet.

Currently I have the copying working fine. I'm currently trying to expand it so it checks if it exists in the currently selected sheet before copying, and then from there expand it to check both sheets, but I'm very new to VBA and excel of this level so I'm stumped.

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim csh As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range

    If ActiveCell.Column = 6 Then
        csh = ActiveCell.Value
        FindString = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Value

        If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
            If Len(csh) > 0 Then
                With Sheets(csh).Range("A:A")
                    Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, LookIn=xlValues, LookAt:xlWhole, _ 
                    SearchOrder: xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:False)
                    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                        MsgBox "ID already used"
                    Else
                        With Sheets(csh)
                            lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        End With
                            Sheets(csh).Cells(lastrow, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Value
                            Sheets(csh).Cells(lastrow, 2).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Value
                            Sheets(csh).Cells(lastrow, 3).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value
                            Sheets(csh).Cells(lastrow, 4).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
                            Sheets(csh).Cells(lastrow, 5).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

What I would expect from this is that, when I change the drop down for a row from A, to B, then back to A, on the 2nd A I would get a Message Box saying "ID already used". I'm not, and I'm not sure why. I think my logic is correct. The ID in all three sheets would be in column A.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of ActiveCell, use Target, that is the cell being changed.

Comment: Then do the Find on each of the two sheets and if they both return Nothing then copy the values. Make sense?

Comment: @SJR It does make sense, but as far as I'm aware what I have above should do it for one sheet. But right now it copies it regardless of if the value is already on the sheet, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, changing the sheet names as necessary.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim FindString As String
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("A") 'change names as necessary
Set ws2 = Worksheets("B")

If Target.Column = 6 Then
    FindString = Target.Offset(0, -5).Value
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        If Len(Target) > 0 Then
            Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A:A").Find(What:=FindString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
            Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=FindString)
            If Not rng1 Is Nothing Or Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "ID already used"
            Else
                With Sheets(Target.Text)
                    lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Cells(lastrow, 1).Resize(, 5).Value = Target.Offset(0, -5).Resize(, 5).Value
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

The problem with ActiveCell is that after you have changed a cell (the Target), that cell is no longer active and so the two are different things. You can easily test this by adding this code to a sheet module, changing a cell and seeing what the message box returns.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
MsgBox ActiveCell.Address
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I couldn't try this over the weekend. I'm trying this now and it still has the same problem - duplicate rows are still copied over. Does it matter if the IDs are all numbers?

Comment: Have you done any debugging, stepped through the code?

Comment: I have, it seems to not be stopping at the 'If Not rng1 Is Nothing Or Not rng2 Is Nothing Then' line, even when they already exist on the sheet. Is there a way to see what the Range variables contain? I tried 'MsgBox rng1' but that didn't work. Neither did Debug.Print rng1

Comment: If you hover over rng1/rng2 when stepping through you should see the values. You could try `rng1.address` (which will error if it's not found).

Comment: Ah, okay, yeah, rng1 and rng2 are always nothing it seems? The ID I'm using is a number - formatting for all columns the ID is in is the same, if that matters. It just doesn't seem to be finding it in the other sheets?

Comment: That means the values are not found. Hard for me to tell but eg look for trailing/leading spaces. Whatever you think is there is not. The code runs when column F is changed and it is searching for the corresponding entry in column A - is that right?